# Google Spreadsheet conditional formatting based on AND/OR

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have the following spreadsheet format:

```
Company     A     B     C
Microsoft         1     1
Google      1     
Samsung           1
```

What would be the custom conditional code based on the following rule:

- Highlight row if cell A is less than cell B AND/OR cell C
- In this case, Microsoft and Samsung would be highlighted

Comment: *"Microsoft and Samsung would be highlighted"*... so just OR then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=OR($B1<$C1,$B1<$D1)
```

with formatting and Range: to suit.